# how to create a spritesheet using node-spritesheet?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, sprite-sheet

I installed node-spritesheet and tried to create a spritesheet like this.

I created main.js and 3 images - image1.png, image2.png and image3.png in my home folder and in the same folder I've another folder called node-modules in which node modules like express, node-spritesheet etc. are present.

This's my main.js file

```
var Builder = require( 'node-spritesheet' ).Builder;

var builder = new Builder({
    outputDirectory: '/home/XYZ',
    outputImage: 'sprite.png',
    outputCss: 'sprite.css',
    selector: '.sprite',
    images: [ 'image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png' ]
});

builder.build( function() {
    console.log( "Built from " + builder.files.length + " images" );
});
```

Next I ran

> node main.js

which gave the following result

```
--------------------------------------------------------------

Building 'default' at pixel ratio 1
--------------------------------------------------------------

/home/XYZ/node_modules/node-spritesheet/lib/imagemagick.js:14
            throw "Error in identify (" + filepath + "): " + (error || stderr);
                                                           ^
Error in identify (image1.png): Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: 1: identify: not found
```

I tried different paths for image like **./image1.png**, **/home/XYZ/image1.png** instead of just **image1.png**.

Can someone please explain why this's happening?

P.S : I'm new to node, so please excuse any silly mistakes I made and correct me.

Comment: Does `XYZ` folder exist in `root` folder?

Comment: XYZ is my home directory

Comment: mean `home` is your `root` directory where `main.js` and `node_modules` folder exist?

Comment: yea, it has both main.js and node_modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be because the command **identify** isn't found, which is in imagemagick module. So it worked fine after installing imagemagick.